# How to use a variable in Get-MailboxFolderPermission

Tags: powershell

I wanted to use a variable for a lawyer's name so I could recycle the same Get-MailboxFolderPermission command, but the syntax doesn't seem to work.

The command by itself would be:
Get-MailboxFolderPermission jdoe:\calendar

But if I try to put "jdoe" in a variable ($lawyer = "jdoe")
and then try to invoke it in the command
Get-MailboxFolderPermission $lawyer:\calendar
it gives an error: 
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

Get-MailboxFolderPermission "$($jdoe):\calendar" doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't produce an accurate output of his calendar permission.

I suspect it has to do with the ":" that is part of the command, but I can't find an article that addresses this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just figured it out based on the error.
Get-CalendarPermission ${jdoe}:\calendar   works properly.